# Difference between C# interface and Haskell Type Class

Tags: c#, haskell, interface, typeclass

I know that there is a similar question here, but I would like to see an example, which clearly shows, what you can not do with `interface` and can with Type Class

For comparison I'll give you an example code:

```
class Eq a where 
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
instance Eq Integer where 
    x == y  =  x `integerEq` y
```

C# code:

```
interface Eq<T> { bool Equal(T elem); }
public class Integer : Eq<int> 
{
     public bool Equal(int elem) 
     {
         return _elem == elem;
     }
}
```

Correct my example, if not correctly understood

Comment: Counterquestion: can you provide default a implementation in c#? Can you make constraint interfaces like `Show a => MyClass a`? And interfaces like functor that work on container types?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me:) Can you give a complete example, otherwise I do not understand

Comment: I believe you can have default implementations in a Haskell typeclass - a C# interface is essentially a contract that the class will provide the defined methods/properties.

Comment: @PaulF what about `abstract class` in this case? or Java interface, where we can have default implementation, as I know

Comment: That is possibly a closer analogy - an abstract class cannot be instantiated itself & may define abstract methods that must be defined in the derived class & virtual methods (=default implementation) which may be overridden.

Comment: In Haskell, can we instantiate an `class Eq` without inheritance? Or I misunderstood something. I do not know well Haskell, so I would like to see an example of advantages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long study of this issue, I came to an easy method of explaining. At least for me it's clear.

Imagine we have method with signature like this

```
public static T[] Sort(T[] array, IComparator<T> comparator) 
{
    ...
}
```

And implementation of `IComparator`:

```
public class IntegerComparator : IComparator<int> { }
```

Then we can write code like this:

```
var sortedIntegers = Sort(integers, new IntegerComparator());
```

We can improve this code, first we create `Dictionary<Type, IComparator>` and fill it:

```
var comparators = new Dictionary<Type, IComparator>() 
{
    [typeof(int)]    = new IntegerComparator(),
    [typeof(string)] = new StringComparator() 
}
```

> Redesigned IComparator interface so that we could write like above
>
> ```
> public interface IComparator {}
> public interface IComparator<T> : IComparator {}
> ```

And after this let's redesign `Sort` method signature

```
public class SortController
{
    public T[] Sort(T[] array, [Injectable]IComparator<T> comparator = null) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you understand we are going to inject `IComparator<T>`, and write code like this:

```
new SortController().Sort<int>(integers, (IComparator<int>)_somparators[typeof(int)])
```

As you already guessed this code will not work for other types until we outline the implementation and add in `Dictionary<Type, IComparator>`

> Notice, the exception we will see only on runtime

And now imagine if this work was done for us by the compiler during build and it threw exception if it could not find the comparator with corresponding types.

For this, we could help the compiler and add a new keyword instead of usage attribute. Out `Sort` method will be look like this:

```
public static T[] Sort(T[] array, implicit IComparator<T> comparator) 
{
    ...
}
```

And code of realization concrete Comparator:

```
public class IntegerComparator : IComparator<int> implicit { }
```

> Note, we use the keyword 'implicit', after this compiler will be able to do
>   routine work, which we wrote above, and the exception will be thrown during
>   compile-time

```
var sortedIntegers = Sort(integers);

// this gives us compile-time error
// because we don't have implementation of IComparator<string> 
var sortedStrings = Sort(strings);
```

And give the name to this style of implementation **Type Class**

```
public class IntegerComparator : IComparator<int> implicit { }
```

I hope that I understood correctly and understandably explained.

PS: The code does not pretend to work.

Answer (score 10):

Typeclasses are resolved based on a type, while interface dispatch happens against an explicit receiver object. Type class arguments are implicitly provided to a function while objects in C# are provided explicitly. As an example, you could write the following Haskell function which uses the `Read` class:

```
readLine :: Read a => IO a
readLine = fmap read getLine
```

which you can then use as:

```
readLine :: IO Int
readLine :: IO Bool
```

and have the appropriate `read` instance provided by the compiler.

You could try to emulate the `Read` class in C# with an interface e.g.

```
public interface Read<T>
{
    T Read(string s);
}
```

but then the implementation of `ReadLine` would need a parameter for the `Read<T>` 'instance' you want:

```
public static T ReadLine<T>(Read<T> r)
{
    return r.Read(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

The `Eq` typeclass requires both arguments have the same type, whereas your `Eq` interface does not since the first argument is implicitly the type of the receiver. You could for example have:

```
public class String : Eq<int>
{
    public bool Equal(int e) { return false; }
}
```

which you cannot represent using `Eq`. Interfaces hide the type of the receiver and hence the type of one of the arguments, which can cause problems. Imagine you have a typeclass and interface for an immutable [heap datastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)):

```
class Heap h where
  merge :: Ord a => h a -> h a -> h a

public interface Heap<T>
{
    Heap<T> Merge(Heap<T> other);
}
```

Merging two binary heaps can be done in O(n) while merging two binomial heaps is possible in O(n log n) and for fibonacci heaps it's O(1). Implementors of the Heap interface do not know the real type of the other heap so is forced to either use a sub-optimal algorithm or use dynamic type checks to discover it. In contrast, types implementing the `Heap` typeclass do know the representation.

Comment: Can you write pseudocode on C#, which will not work, but in Haskell it will be possible to implement?

Comment: @kogoia - Pseudocode for what? You can emulate typeclasses in C# by manually passing 'instances' around (ignoring aspects of the Haskell type system that C# doesn't support like higher-kinded polymorphism).

Comment: As I understand, if we have `T sort(T[], Comparer<T>)` function, and after this we implement `Comparer<int>` and call `sort(integers)`,  compiler check whether there is an implementation of type `Comparer<int>` and if it exists then inject into method, otherwise build error. I understood correctly?

Comment: I read an article about Scala, here proper definition of function `def sort[T](elements: Seq[T])(implicit comparator: Comparer[T]): Seq[T]` and call this function like this `sort(integers)`

Comment: and type class implementation `implicit def ListComparator[V](implicit comparator: Comparator[V]) = new Comparator[List[V]] { ... }`

Comment: @kogoia - Yes Haskell provides the typeclass instances for you implicitly. Scala has implicit parameters which can be used to emulate typeclasses, although Haskell only allows one typeclass instance for each type while the scala approach allows you to have multiple instances i.e. you could have multiple `Comparer[Int]` instances. Haskell requires you to define a new type for each instance you want to define (see for example `Product` and `Sum` in [Data.Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html).

Comment: I myself tried to answer on this question, can you look at this and edit if there are errors in the explanation. Thank you for respond

Answer (score 7):

A C# interface defines a set of methods that must be implemented. A Haskell type class defines a set of methods that must be implemented (and *possibly* a set of default implementations for some of the methods). So there's a lot of similarities there.

(I guess an important difference is that in C#, an interface *is* a type, whereas Haskell regards types and type classes as strictly separate things.)

The *key* difference is that in C#, when you define a type (i.e., write a class), you define exactly what interfaces it implements, and this is frozen for all time. In Haskell, you can *add* new interfaces to an existing type at any time.

For example, if I write a new `SerializeToXml` interface in C#, I cannot then make `double` or `String` implement that interface. But in Haskell, I can define my new `SerializeToXml` type class, and then make all the standard, built-in types implement that interface (`Bool`, `Double`, `Int`...)

The other thing is how polymorphism works in Haskell. In an OO language, you dispatch on the type of the method the object is being invoked on. In Haskell, the type that the method is implemented for can appear *anywhere* in the type signature. Most particularly, `read` dispatches on the *return type* you want — something you usually can't do at all in OO languages, not even with function overloading.

Also, in C# it's kind of hard to say "these two arguments must have *the same* type". Then again, OO is predicated on the Liskov substitution principal; two classes that both descend from `Customer` should be interchangeable, so why would you want to constrain two `Customer` objects to both be *the same* type of customer?

Come to think of it, OO languages do method lookup at *run-time*, whereas Haskell does method lookup at *compile-time*. This isn't immediately obvious, but Haskell polymorphism actually works more like C++ templates than usual OO polymorphism. (But that's not especially to do with type classes, it's just how Haskell does polymorphism as such.)

Comment: It is difficult to realize all this for me. How often do we need it in our daily work? The advantage is worth which time need to spend?

Comment: Can you write pseudocode on C#, which will not work, but in Haskell it will be possible to implement?

Answer (score 6):

Others have already provided excellent answers.

I only want to add a practical example about their differences. Suppose we want to model a "vector space" typeclass/interface, which contains the common operations of 2D, 3D, etc. vectors.

In Haskell:

```hs
class Vector a where
   scale :: a -> Double -> a
   add :: a -> a -> a

data Vec2D = V2 Double Double
instance Vector (Vec2D) where
   scale s (V2 x y) = V2 (s*x) (s*y)
   add (V2 x1 y1) (V2 x2 y2) = V2 (x1+x2) (y2+y2)

-- the same for Vec3D
```

In C#, we might try the following *wrong* approach (I hope I get the syntax right)

```
interface IVector {
   IVector scale(double s);
   IVector add(IVector v);
}
class Vec2D : IVector {
   double x,y;
   // constructor omitted
   IVector scale(double s) { 
     return new Vec2D(s*x, s*y);
   }
   IVector add(IVector v) { 
     return new Vec2D(x+v.x, y+v.y);
   }
}
```

We have two issues here.

First, `scale` returns only an `IVector`, a supertype of the actual `Vec2D`. This is bad, because scaling does not preserve the type information.

Second, `add` is ill-typed! We can't use `v.x` since `v` is an arbitrary `IVector` which might not have the `x` field.

Indeed, the interface itself is wrong: the `add` method promises that any vector must be summable with any other vector, so we must be able to sum 2D and 3D vectors, which is nonsense.

The usual solution is to switch to [F-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification) AKA CRTP or whatever it's being called these days:

```
interface IVector<T> {
   T scale(double s);
   T add(T v);
}
class Vec2D : IVector<Vec2D> {
   double x,y;
   // constructor omitted
   Vec2D scale(double s) { 
     return new Vec2D(s*x, s*y);
   }
   Vec2D add(Vec2D v) { 
     return new Vec2D(x+v.x, y+v.y);
   }
}
```

The first time a programmer meets this, they are usually puzzled by the seemingly "recursive" line `Vec2D : IVector<Vec2D>`. I surely was :) Then we get used to this and accept it as an idiomatic solution.

Type classes arguably have a nicer solution here.