# Haskell's type classes vs. Java function overloading

Tags: java, haskell, typeclass

I have been trying to understand Haskell's type classes and have read often that they are more general than java interfaces. Thinking about it I wondered whether the comparison between interfaces and type classes is actually not where the relationship lies. I think type classes should rather be compared to overloaded methods. Consider the following Haskell code:

```hs
class Divide a b c where
    divi :: a -> b -> c

instance Divide Integer Integer Double where
    divi x y = (fromIntegral x) `div` (fromIntegral y)

instance Divide Double Double Double where
    divi x y = x `div` y

instance Divide Double Integer Double where
    divi x y = x `div` (fromIntegral y)

instance Divide Integer Double Double where
    divi x y = (fromIntegral x) `div` y
```

Writing it "functionally" in Java (e.g. using static methods like functions) I would translate this to the following

```
static class Math {

    static double divi(int a, int b) {
        return a / b;
    }

    static double divi(double a, double b) {
        // in java the implementation is always the same because the compiler does the trick, but that is irrelevant
        return a / b;
    }

    static double divi(double a, int b) {
        return a / b;
    }

    static double divi(int a, double b) {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

I know this is not exactly the same since in my Java version there is no equivalent of the `Divide` Type class itself only the overloaded functions are present. But I think this comes much closer to an equivalent to the Haskell code than interface inheritance and method overriding.

What do you guys think about that argument?

PS: I haven't tested my code neither in Haskell nor Java, since it's only to get the point across. Please feel free to correct any bugs.

Comment: No, one of the nice things about Haskell is that you can also define such `instance`s inductively, like `instance Eq a => Eq [a]`. So given the elements can be checked for equality, you define the list to be valid for equality. Anther important difference is that you enforce that an `instance` must implement *all* the necessary functions. So if you make a `Num`, it does *not* suffice to only implement `(+)`, you have to impelemnt the entire "pack".

Comment: Very similar question to [Difference between C# interface and Haskell Type Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233416/difference-between-c-sharp-interface-and-haskell-type-class)

Comment: Closely related: [*Typeclasses and overloading, what is the connection?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47971360/2751851) (I'm not entirely sure whether it is a dupl*cate; I'll leave it up to you and our fellow users to decide.)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem correct me if I'm wrong: when comparing type classes with interfaces, the same can be said about java interfaces: they do not allow inductive definition, because that is not one of java's features

Comment: @JohnSmith: well the question of course always boils down to "what do you consider to be an interface", etc? Typeclasses are not bound to functional programming: functional programming can exist without type classes, and imperative programming can have typeclasses. But crucial is always how those concepts are defined.